# Angular Universal not running any functions after Refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mean-stack, angular-universal

This is my server.ts
I want to implement universal only in signin page.
Everything (Universal and all functionalitites) is working fine unless I refresh signin page.
Then page becomes pure static, even 'view password' functionality is also not working, any JavaScript is not executed at all.
Can someone please suggest me something, I would be highly grateful.

```
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/cpaVaultUI/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('/auth/signin', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(distFolder+'/index.html');
  });
  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

> Edit

I found out that when I implement Universal in whole application, then from start only no java script is executing.
In short from start only client side is not able to takeover.

Please help!